# Сократить написание объявления объекта через массив и .map

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции, объекты, map

В общем, вроде простая задача - уместить эти 2 строчки в одну:

```
let pairs = {};
Array.from(str.matchAll(regexp)).map(val => pairs[val.index + 1] = val[0]);
```

Но решение я так найти и не смог. Вкратце, код создаёт объект на основе массива используя  `.map`, но при этом объявляет пустой объект, чего нужно избежать... Буду очень благодарен если кто-нибудь с этим поможет

Comment: А пример регулярки и строки?

Comment: Они будут произвольными. Например /./g и 'apple'

Comment: `map` вернет еще и новый массив, что тут явно не нужно. Для простого перебора более уместен `forEach`. Для конкретного случая - `reduce`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> уместить эти 2 строчки в одну

Заменить `map` на `reduce`...

```
let pairs = Array.from(str.matchAll(regexp)).reduce((o, val) => (o[val.index + 1] = val[0], o), {});
```

Еще вот так сократить можно...

```
let pairs = [...str.matchAll(regexp)].reduce((o, val) => (o[val.index + 1] = val[0], o), {});
```

Comment: О, спасибо, сейчас проверю

Comment: Да, всё работает (использовал первый вариант), спасибо большое

Comment: Если заниматься минимизацией, то можно `[...str.matchAll(regexp)].reduce((o, {0: v, index: i}) => (o[i+1] = v, o), {});`